# Node route intemitenatly works

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Using node I am having troubles where I have created 2 routes.
Sometimes 1 works and the other doesn't. Sometimes the other works and the first one doesn't. Sometimes both don't work.
The browser just spins and times out.
This is without me making any changes to them.

I am having troubles with the routes

/viewRecords/bne
&
/viewRecords/ssc

/ & /viewRecords work fine.

This is the current version of the route I created.
I have also made seperate routes with the same result.
eg: router.get('/bne')
&
router.get('/ssc')

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
    const Datastore = require('nedb');
    const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');

const bneDB = new Datastore('databases/BNE.db');
const sscDB = new Datastore('databases/SSC.db');
    bneDB.loadDatabase();
    sscDB.loadDatabase();

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', `${__dirname}/views`);
app.set('layout', 'layout/layout');

app.use(expressLayouts);
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json({ limit: '1mb' }));

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));

const registerRoute = require('./routes/register');
    app.use('/', registerRoute);

const viewRecordsRoute = require('./routes/viewRecords');
    app.use('/viewRecords', viewRecordsRoute);
```

viewRecordsRoute.js

```
const express = require('express');
    const router = express.Router();
const Datastore = require('nedb');

const bneDB = new Datastore('databases/BNE.db');
const sscDB = new Datastore('databases/SSC.db');
    bneDB.loadDatabase();
    sscDB.loadDatabase();

router.get('/', (request, response) => {
    response.render('viewRecords.ejs');
});

router.get('/:id', (request, response) => {
    if (request.params.id == "bne") {
        bneDB.find({}, (err, output) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                    return;
            }
            response.render('siteRecords.ejs', {
                site: 'Redbank',
                records: output
            });
                return;
        });
    }
    else {
        sscDB.find({}, (err, output) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                    return;
            }
            response.render('siteRecords.ejs', {
                site: 'Coolum',
                records: output
            });
                return;
        });
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Well, if this is not about the `style.css` file, then I don't see enough information in your question to have any idea how to help so I'll delete my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it was the limitations of nedb.
When I removed nedb, everything worked fine.
I halved to size of the database and everything worked fine.
I ended up migrating to mongo db and everything worked fine.
It really seemed like I hit the limit of nedb.

I have been using nedb for quite a while for smaller projects without issue.
This just happened to get bigger and bigger.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the problematic routes are the ones that run db queries. If an error occurs, you just console.log the error, but you don't return anything to browser as response. Instead of `return;` by itself, try `return response.send(err);`  That ensures always something is sent to browser.

Of course, you can handle the error in other ways too.

Comment: I gave that a try and the same issue.
Saying it's the db. I did remove the db query and just responded with the page itself and worked. So it must be a database issue.